# Why are game engine properties changing 1 tick late?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

When I pull out a weapon (weapon-switch), a prop ("Timer_Activate") is set to 10, the number of frames for the weapon-switch animation. If you swap weapons, it will set the prop to 20, and the prop will drop every tick by 1 till it reaches 0. Once the prop is at 0, you can fire. The problem is, if you swap between a weapon, and you hold the fire-button, **you will fire 1 bullet before the prop turns into 20**. This happens *all the time* and can be a cheat to gain fast-firing weapons. How can I fix this "lag"? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Use my [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36654) to see the issue firsthand:
Press 1 or 2 for any of the 2 weapons, and *make sure you are holding down left-click as you are swapping*, you will fire 1 bullet, **then** the animation plays and the timer is set to 20.

If you cannot download the .blend or can't find the issue, be sure to check out a gif of the problem [here](http://recordit.co/hlYwskyxGa). (**The gif is slightly modified but you can still see the issue.**):

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to set it to 46...?

Comment: @someonewithpc I agree that it should be closed as either unclear, or too localized; however even mods can not close a question with an open bounty.

Comment: It would help if you posted your code or .blend, without which we don't have much hope of debugging the problem..

Comment: @gandalf3 I am using logic bricks, so I don't have any code. I heard that logic bricks sometimes need 1 tick to do an action. This might be the problem. Is this true?

Comment: @blackhole We want to be able to help you, but this becomes difficult when you don't cooperate with us. It's okay if you don't want to share a .blend you put lots of your own time into (thats completely understandable), but if that's the issue you can just say so. Restating the problem in bold isn't going to help anyone. Take a moment to look your question from the point of view of someone ready to donate their time to debug and answer it. Would *you* want to spend your time on this question? Or would you rather answer a question which is asked respectfully and includes extra info you ask for?

Comment: Communication is important. If there is some issue you are having with the site's policies or features, you are encouraged to bring it up on [meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm working on a .blend but it seems confusing to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem

The problem was that, your integer property **Timer** was *still equal to 45* when the weapon was switched, *for exactly one logic tick*, allowing a shot to escape. Then, one tick later, the message actuator could deliver the message to assign the property **Timer** to 0.

### Reason

The message system actually takes one logic tick from the time the actuator receives the positive pulse from the controller, to the time when the message sensor on the receiving end receives the message and sends the positive pulse to it's controller(s).

### How to fix it

I have un-checked the the check boxes on all of the logic we aren't using so it will be easier to see the necessary change. (re-check them before testing)

[image]

Your end result should look like this, only without the actuators on **Active_Determiner**

Essentially, all you need to do is Delete the logic bricks marked by a red box, and connect the bricks where the Blue lines are.

This will completely cut out the message system, (and the one-tick delay) and directly connect the bricks instead.
[image]

result:

## It works! - yay!

[image]

If you didn't understand that, don't feel bad (logic can be confusing.) here is the blend file in case you did get confused.

[image]

Comment: I knew this was the issue! Thanks for the answer, but I have my weapons and armatures in another scene. Should I just move the determiner object to the other scene?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best way to do it. (and make it by far easier.)

Comment: That strategy would cost me days to accomplish considering that I have *tons* of objects that rely on copying properties from it. This would be difficult. Can I use python or any other way to fix this?

Comment: to quote from the documentation, *the python controller is essentially an infinity customizable logic brick* so obviously it is possible, (But I have no idea how.) Have you considered trying to duplicate the determiner object to the other scene and have the same events that trigger it to change, make both of them change?

Comment: "Have you considered trying to duplicate the determiner object to the other scene and have the same events that trigger it to change, make both of them change?" I am confused. What do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is, have your empty in the first scene so your other objects can copy from it, and then make another empty in the other scene with the same logic, so your weapons can directly access those properties, and simply make the events (example, a collision) send a message to the empty in  the other scene, and have it directly connected to the empty in it's scene.

Comment: What a relief. I appeciate this a lot by the way. I have linked the empty in the weapons scene, duplicated it, removed the linked one, and used the new one. Everything *seems* fine so far, is this correct? :)

Comment: You should have an empty in both scenes, both with their properties changing at the same time.